# Testing Anchor program with solana-program-test crate

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-client, solana-program-test, solana-sdk

I was trying to test my anchor program with rust tests. Test written in Typescript are working fine. I am getting with `cargo test`:

```
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread 'testing_initialize' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IoError(Custom { kind: Other, error: "the request exceeded its deadline" })', programs/playground/tests/initialize.rs:66:10
```

Here is program Code:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod playground {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        println!("Program Log: {:?}, {:?}, {:?}",ctx.accounts.global_state.key(),ctx.accounts.owner,ctx.accounts.global_state.key() );
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
    )]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = owner,
        seeds = ["seed".as_bytes()],
        bump,
        space = 200+8,
    )]
    pub global_state: Box<Account<'info, GlobalState>>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct GlobalState {
    pub counter: u32,
}
```

Test file :

```
use anchor_lang::{system_program, solana_program::{self}, prelude::Pubkey};
use solana_program_test::{ProgramTest, processor, tokio};
use solana_sdk::{account::Account, instruction::Instruction, signature::Keypair, transaction::Transaction, signer::Signer};
use anchor_lang::InstructionData;
use anchor_lang::ToAccountMetas;

#[tokio::test]
async fn testing_initialize() {
    let mut program = ProgramTest::new(
        "anchor playground",
        playground::id(),
        // the entrypoint function is generated by the #[program] macro
        processor!(playground::entry),
    );

    let system_program = system_program::ID;
    let token_program_id = anchor_spl::token::ID;
    let rent = solana_program::sysvar::rent::ID;
    let associated_token_program_id = anchor_spl::associated_token::ID;
    println!(
        "{} / {} / {} / {}",
        system_program, token_program_id, rent, associated_token_program_id
    );
    
    let owner = Keypair::new();

    program.add_account(
        owner.pubkey(),
        Account {
            lamports: 1_000_000_000,
            ..Account::default()
        },
    );
    let global_state = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"seed"], &playground::id()).0;

    program.add_account(
        owner.pubkey(),
        Account {
            lamports: 1_000_000_000,
            ..Account::default()
        },
    );

    let initalize_ix =Instruction {
        program_id: playground::ID,
        data: playground::instruction::Initialize{}
        .data(),
        accounts: playground::accounts::Initialize {
            owner: owner.pubkey(),
            global_state,
            rent,
            system_program,
        }
        .to_account_metas(None),
    };
    let mut program_context = program.start_with_context().await;

    let mut initalize_tx = Transaction::new_with_payer(&[initalize_ix],Some(&owner.pubkey()));
    let recent_blockhash = program_context.last_blockhash.clone();

    initalize_tx.partial_sign(&[&owner], recent_blockhash);
    program_context
        .banks_client
        .process_transaction(initalize_tx)
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

also the cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "playground"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "playground"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.24.2"

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "1.9.29"
anchor-spl = "0.24.2"
solana-sdk = "1.9.29"
```

Full Logs with RUST_BACKTRACE

```
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
thread 'testing_initialize' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IoError(Custom { kind: Other, error: "the request exceeded its deadline" })', programs/playground/tests/initialize.rs:66:10
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/result.rs:1785:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/result.rs:1078:23
   4: initialize::testing_initialize::{{closure}}
             at ./tests/initialize.rs:62:5
   5: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:91:19
   6: <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/future/future.rs:124:9
   7: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::Inner<P>::block_on::{{closure}}::{{closure}}
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:240:62
   8: tokio::coop::with_budget::{{closure}}
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/coop.rs:106:9
   9: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:445:16
  10: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:421:9
  11: tokio::coop::with_budget
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/coop.rs:99:5
  12: tokio::coop::budget
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/coop.rs:76:5
  13: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::Inner<P>::block_on::{{closure}}
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:240:39
  14: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::enter::{{closure}}
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:349:29
  15: tokio::macros::scoped_tls::ScopedKey<T>::set
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/macros/scoped_tls.rs:61:9
  16: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::enter
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:349:5
  17: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::Inner<P>::block_on
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:230:9
  18: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::InnerGuard<P>::block_on
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:501:9
  19: tokio::runtime::basic_scheduler::BasicScheduler<P>::block_on
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/basic_scheduler.rs:186:24
  20: tokio::runtime::Runtime::block_on
             at /Users/sushantchandla/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.14.1/src/runtime/mod.rs:461:46
  21: initialize::testing_initialize
             at ./tests/initialize.rs:62:5
  22: initialize::testing_initialize::{{closure}}
             at ./tests/initialize.rs:8:7
  23: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
  24: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/e092d0b6b43f2de967af0887873151bb1c0b18d3/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.


failures:
    testing_initialize

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 60.16s
```

Also the link to the Repo: https://github.com/SushantChandla/anchor-playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the test with cargo test-bpf and specify the tests. So command is:

```
cargo test-bpf --test initialize -- testing_iniitalize
```