# Solana program test coverage

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, solana-program-test

Is there any tool to measure test coverage of test written in rust with solana-program-test crate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure test coverage for Anchor program?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2610/how-to-measure-test-coverage-for-anchor-program)

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, related info:

https://crates.io/crates/solana-program-test

https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/1.15.2/solana_program_test/

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/ada6136a6c666c6733d69b8aca85e9f88865bc7e/program-test

In other entry an user give an explanation that this may is not posible:

[How to measure test coverage for Anchor program?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2610/how-to-measure-test-coverage-for-anchor-program)